# Sending or receiving data from and to a Wiimote using chrome.hid and the default Windows 7 HID driver does not work

Tags: windows, bluetooth, google-chrome-app, hid, wiimote

and thanks for taking the time to read this.

**Concept**

Connect a wiimote to a windows (or mac) using the default HID driver and service (because BT L2CAP is not yet supported in chrome.bluetoothSocket). I wan't to send and receive data from the device; buttons, gyroscope, IR camera, etc ... .

**My setup (relevant parts)**

- Macbook pro (installed Yosemite)
- Chrome Canary (Version 41.0.2246.0 canary (64-bit)), running in verbose logging mode
- Windows 7 through bootcamp
- Wiimote (Nintendo RVL-CNT-01)

**Code to send data to device**

```
var _wiimote = this;
var bytes = new Uint8Array(21);

var reportId = 0x11;
bytes[0] = 0x10;

chrome.hid.send(_wiimote.connectionId, reportId, bytes.buffer, function() {
  if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
    console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
    console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
  }
  console.log("Wiimote send data");

  chrome.hid.receive(_wiimote.connectionId, function(reportId, data) {
      if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
        return;
      }

      console.log("done receiving.");
      console.log("received:" + data.byteLength);
    });
});
```

**Expected behavior?**

Light up the first LED and stop the blinking that starts when connection, but not pairing, the device.

**Actual behavior?**

The console shows "Wiimote send data" but the LEDs do not react on the sent report.

So this code doesn't do much, but according to the documentation on wiibrew(see resources below).
It should send to the wiimote to light up the first LED. This goes for any output report I'm sending to the device. It does react when I use wrong reportIds or different byte lengths, then it fails.

Next up would be the receiving part, if I were to send anything (really any data) to reportId 0x15 on the wiimote, it should send me an information report. I've tried polling for messages like this:

**Code to receive data from the device**

```
var _wiimote = this;

var pollForInput = function() {
  chrome.hid.receive(_wiimote.connectionId, function(reportId, data) {
    console.log("receiving something",reportId);

    if (_wiimote.pollReceive) {
      setTimeout(pollForInput, 0);
    }
  });
};
```

**Expected behavior?**

After sending 0x00 to the reportId 0x15 I should receive an information report from the wiimote device.

**Actual behavior?**

I've never received anything in the console output indicating communication from the device.

**Resources used**

- http://wiibrew.org/wiki/Wiimote
- https://developer.chrome.com/apps/hid

Comment: Well, now I'm bringing my Wiimote to the office on Monday. I'll let you know what I find out.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the interest Reilly, I've had some success in communicating with the Wiimote through apps based on the Wiimote .NET library (http://wiimotelib.codeplex.com/), and I've opened up the code (Wiimote.cs) to see what they are doing right and what I'm doing wrong ... there seems little or no diff in the code they wrote compared to mine. Except they are controlling the first byte and use it as the report ID. I'm suspecting that chrome.hid prepends the first byte itself. Nevertheless, no response from the wiimote in chrome apps yet.

Comment: Yes, Chrome prepends the report ID itself.

Comment: I tried this myself and until Windows decided it didn't want to pair with the device anymore I was able to get some input events. I'll post a sample app if I get it working consistently.